# error when getting value from list in html?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

we are creating one jQuery mobile app in that app, I have to bind the webservice data in to list in HTML and when I click the first items in the list, it redirect to second page which I created in same page seperated with div tag and display the relavent information which i selected from the list. In addition to that i stored the web service result in an array.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title><br />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedValut()
 {
var list_value = $(this).attr('searchlist');
alert(list_value);
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Page one starts-->
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="page1content">
         <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="searchlist">
            <li id="search">
                <a href="#pagetwo" value="Selected one" onclick="GetSelectedValut()">Selected one</a>
             </li>
            <li id="search1" onclick="GetSelectedValut()">
                <a href="#detailpage">Selected two</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#detailpage">Selected three</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#detailpage">Selected four</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#detailpage">Selected five</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#detailpage">Selected six</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Page one ends-->
<!-- Page two starts-->
<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    Welcome to Div two
        </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- page two ends -->
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one I'm sure you get result:

> ```
> <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="searchlist">
>                 <li>
>                     <a href="#" id="selected one">Selected one</a>
>                  </li>
>
>     </ul>
>
>
>
>
>  $('#searchlist li a').bind("click",function() 
>       {
>
>           var selectedId = $(this).attr("id");
>           alert("your selected ID is "+ selectedId);
>
>       });
> ```

Answer (score 3):

There is no attribute called "seachlist"...

You assigned the same id to several elements...this will cause problems...

If you are trying to get the text of the a tag, then change #detailpage to .detailpage and then use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.detailpage').bind('click', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
</script>
```

Advantage:  No "onclick" in your code...this is called unobtrustive javascript and it's way cooler than mucking up your html with javascript stuff.

Even better, to pass a value, instead of worrying about the link content, assign whatever value you want to the item's ID and fetch that.

Enjoy.

Jquery Refs: 
.ready : http://api.jquery.com/ready/

.bind : http://api.jquery.com/bind/

.text : http://api.jquery.com/text/

UPDATE:  Id you want to update some div on the page with the text we retrieved it's simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.detailpage').bind('click', function() {
    var thetext = $(this).text();
    $('div#pagetwo').append(thetext);
  });
});
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Append will add text indefinitely, to the end of the element.

Or if you want to update a specific part of the page 2 div, you would need to add a class to it like .content and then you could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.detailpage').bind('click', function() {
    var thetext = $(this).text();
    $('div#pagetwo.content').html(thetext);
  });
});
</script>
```

.html will fill the element with what you pass it.

http://api.jquery.com/html/

If you wanted to wrap the content in a paragraph tag or something before sending it along:

```
$('div#pagetwo.content').html('<p>' + thetext + '</p>');
```

Comment: <!-- Page two starts--> <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">     <div data-role="header">         <h1>Header</h1>     </div>     <div data-role="content">     Welcome to Div two         </div>     <div data-role="footer">         <h1>Footer</h1>     </div> </div> <!-- page two ends -->

Comment: i want to displayin page two(div) there?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question...Can you elaborate on what you are asking?

Comment: I seee...I think you want the page2 div updated with the text from the link?  In that case it's simple...I'll edit my answer with code for that.  Consult the jquery api, this is all well documented and fairly clear (but maybe I've just gotten used to it!)